Can Google Sign-In Be Used Without Firebase in Flutter Now?
I am implementing Google Sign-In in my Flutter app without Firebase, but I am encountering the following error:
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:, null, null)
When I integrate Google Sign-In with Firebase, everything works fine. However, I want to implement it independently of Firebase. (The app is already published on the Play Store)
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Added the google_sign_in package to my pubspec.yaml.
Followed the basic implementation steps provided in the package documentation.
I did not make any modifications to build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml

Does the ApiException: 10 error indicate missing configurations in build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml, or Google Cloud Console?
What specific configurations are required for using Google Sign-In without Firebase, especially for a published app?

"Can Google Sign-In Be Used Without Firebase in Flutter Now?"
That should always have been possible. If you can't get it to work, please post a minimal repro. To learn more on how to do that, and why it's so useful: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
